# Display checkboxes values from ACF (Wordpress) on front

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having some trouble trying to display checkboxes values created with ACF.
I have a group of 12 checkboxes made with ACF, where each checkbox is a month:
jan : Jan / feb : Feb / mar : Mar / etc.

What i need to achieve is to display all of those 12 values in the frontend, with a particular CSS class if the month has been checked in the backend. For example, if the user checks "Jan", "Apr", "Jul" and "Sep":

```
<span class="selected">Jan</span>
<span>Feb</span>
<span>Mar</span>
<span class="selected">Apr</span>
<span>May</span>
<span>Jun</span>
<span class="selected">Jul</span>
<span>Ago</span>
<span class="selected">Sep</span>
<span>Oct</span>
<span>Nov</span>
<span>Dec</span>
```

Using the example code from the docs  (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/), I'm only getting the selected months but not all months in the frontend:

```
<span>Jan</span>
<span>Apr</span>
<span>Jul</span>
<span>Sep</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check below code and output it helps you.

```
<?php $allCheckbox = get_field('month_checked_boxes'); //Checked value from backend

$field_key = "field_593f77cdc5068"; //Get value using key
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$field = get_field_object($field_key, $post_id);
foreach($field['choices'] as $lab => $val){
if(in_array($val, $allCheckbox)){
    $checked = 'checked = "checked"';   
    $enable = '';       
} else {
    $checked = '';
    $enable = 'disabled=""';
} ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="month" id="month" value="<?php echo $lab; ?>" <?php echo $enable; ?> <?php echo $checked; ?> /><?php echo $val; ?><br>
```

**Please change field key as par your checkbox field from ACF.** Also check output below.

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kushal.
Your code displays all twelve checkboxes, but all the checkboxes always appears disabled and unchecked on frontend, although i did check some of them on the backend.

Comment: If you want to enable the same then please remove disabled attribute from to input type checkbox and try again. if my answer help please accept my answer.

Comment: The problem is that now i'm getting all 12 checkboxes enabled. The checkboxes marked / checked on the backend (Jan, Apr, Jul and Sep) should be displayed on as checked on frontend, just like your output image. All other months should be displayed too, but disabled.

Comment: Please check my edited code now which months are checked from backed are only enable all other months are disable.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine now. One thing to note: the returned value on front end of the checkbox field in ACF, must be "Label" (not "Value" or "Both / Array").