# How do I display both the checkboxes and choices from ACF (Wordpress) on front-end?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 3 checkbox fields that I  have created in Advanced Custom Fields:
Award nominations open
Award nominations close
Award winners announced

I want it so that they all appear on the front-end and when the web editor selects the checkbox in the back-end a tick appears on the front-end.

I have tried using the code on the following post, as it is exactly what I want, but it crashes my site.
[Display checkboxes values from ACF (Wordpress) on front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44511285/display-checkboxes-values-from-acf-wordpress-on-front)

```
<div>
 <?php
  $field = get_field_object('table_dates');
  $field_key = "field_5d71ca56bf09b";
   if( $field['choices'] ): ?>
   <ul>
    <?php foreach( $field['choices'] as $value => $label ): ?>
     <li><?php echo $label; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This code shows the choices, how do I show the ticks like it appears on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little so that `get_field_object()` include current post id (assuming that your code is inside The Loop). That way you have access to currently checked items inside `$field['value']` array.

Also added the `if` statement to add class "active"  to all `li` elements that are checked.

```
<div>
 <?php               
 $field = get_field_object('field_5d71ca56bf09b', get_the_ID());
 if( $field['choices'] ): ?>
  <ul>
   <?php foreach( $field['choices'] as $value => $label ): ?>
    <li <?php echo ( in_array($value, $field['value']) ? 'class="active"' : '' ) ?>><?php echo $label; ?></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: The checkboxes are still not appearing.